# GA4 events stopped suddenly. Custom events are not triggering properly

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am working on a wordpress website and its GA4 event tracking.
I have added two custom events for two form submissions. Events are based on the thank you page visited after the form submission.

event_name = page_view
page_location = https://wwww.example.com/thank-you-1 for form_submission_1

and

event_name = page_view
page_location = https://wwww.example.com/thank-you-2 for form_submission_2

Similarly, when a user completes a booking from the site, he/she is redirected to a thank you page. On this page I have added scripts for booking_event and purchase event.

Here I attach the details pushed to datalayer from the thank you page.

```
window.dataLayer.push({
    "bookingAmount":10007,
    "event":"booking_page",
    "bookingCurrency":"CAD"
});
dataLayer.push({ ecommerce: null });
dataLayer.push({
    "event":"purchase",
    "ecommerce":{
        "transactiond_id":69803,
        "value":10064,
        "tax":10100,
        "currency":"CAD",
        "items":[{
            "item_id":7018,
            "price":10006,
            "item_name":"Booking Name"
        }]
    }
});
```

The custom events were logged in GA4 till 25th August. But from 26th onwards none of the above mentioned events were logged.
When I checked the website with the "Tag Assistant" extension in chrome, the tags were not detected some times. It felt something like lazy loading. If I am scrolling through the page, some times the tags appear and sometimes they are not detected.

Could someone please point out the issue that could cause the issue with tracking the events?